# Facebook with Strophe and punjab

Tags: facebook, ejabberd, strophe

I am new to xmpp.I created my own ejabberd server and tried to
implement facebook chat through it, but it is giving the response as "
remote connection failed". I also tried with punjab but not
successful. Can anyone please tell me the configuration settings to be
modified or added in ejabberd or punjab.
I tried using "chat.facebook.com" as host name and 5222 as port but I
m not sure about where to set these values in my configuration
files.Can anyone solve this issue??

Thanks,
Ramya

Answer (score 0):

Could you make sure that you have pyOpenSSL installed? I faced the same problem and it was the SSL that made the difference.

http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/Downloads